# how to convert the parameter to pass through http

Tags: c#, urlencode

I have russian word `привет` browser as it converts `ïðèâåò`.

I use  `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str)`

But this not helped.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you want to do, what you are doing and what actually happens?

Comment: I send post request through HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 2):

Try `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str)` instead.  You *encode* a string to transmit it via http; you *decode* it to display it in its original form.